# Its is possible that visible all child element in ListView when adapter call

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hi Kindly suggest me  that how i can  visible all child element in ListView Adapter.Actually i want to hold all child object at same time when adapter call.Suppose my list make with a 8 child but at a time only 5 is visible on my handset .So i can access only 5 child object but i want to access all 8 child object.

That is possible in ListView or i should make cutome listview.

Comment: you can get the child elements of a listview through the adapter. But I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: kindly once again read my problem.

Comment: like how to read non visible element in ListView

Comment: can u explain your question again ?

Comment: What is the correct way to modify all child elements (not only the visible ones) of a listview.